# Postgresql how to use IN for multiple column text match

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT * FROM user_follow WHERE (post, "user", type, following)
IN ((25, 1, 'pc' || 'pl' || 'pf', true), (25, 2, 'pc' || 'cc'|| 'cl', true))
```

In the third column I would like to match either 'pc', 'pl', 'pf'. I do not believe I am using right syntax as I get no result when I should and also I have tried using OR instead of || but it also does not work. What's the correct way of doing this?

I still need the multiple `IN` query that matches the exact requirements in the inner brackets

Comment: the In syntax is like.. Where column In (value1, value2, value 3)... This means the value of column could be value1, or value2 or value3

Comment: I mean one of exact match of the values in the inner bracket but third column could be option of one of the three

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`||` does string concatenation.

It looks like you want

```
SELECT * FROM user_follow
WHERE post=25
AND (
    ("user" = 1 AND type IN ('pc', 'pl', 'pf'))
    OR ("user" = 2 AND type IN ('pc', 'cc', 'cl'))
)
AND following=true
```

You could also define the possible combinations like this:

```
with params(u, t) as values (
    (1, array['pc', 'pl', 'pf']),
    (2, array['pc', 'cc', 'cl'])
)
select "user".* from "user", params
where post=25
and "user"=u
and type=any(t)
and following=true
```

Comment: I still have to be able to match multiple `IN` because I am using dataloader

Comment: like how I am trying to retrieve two results in one query above

Comment: The number of results depends on what you have in your table. It will be from 0 to 6 records.

Comment: But then what if types I want to query are different for user 1 and user 2?

Comment: @forJ then you might use a CTE to generate possible combinations but that wasn't your question. Please fix your question with your *complete* and *precise* requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always rewrite it by using plain logical operators, something like this...

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    user_follow
WHERE
    (
        post = 25,
        AND "user" = 1
        AND type IN ('pc', 'pl', 'pf')
        AND = true
    )
    OR (
        post = 25,
        AND "user" = 2
        AND type IN ('pc', 'cc', 'cl')
        AND = true
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query like below:

```
SELECT *
  FROM user_follow
 WHERE ("user" IN ('pc', 'pl', 'pf') AND (post, type, following) IN ((25, 1, true)
     OR "user" IN ('pc', 'cc', 'cl') AND (post, type, following) IN ((25, 2, true));
```

Let me know if it fulfils your requirement.

Thanks,
Idrees